# How to set class=service-block sizes to a uniform height?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, blogdown

I'm adjusting the html / css on a hugo theme, but can't find resources on setting text boxes to a uniform height. Image shows current boxes, with height varying according to amount of text.

The text boxes look like:

[image]

The theme partial /layouts/partials/service.html looks like this:

```
            {{"<!-- /section title -->" | safeHTML }}
            {{ range .Site.Data.service.serviceItem}}
            {{"<!-- Single Service Item -->" | safeHTML }}
            <article class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-12 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="500ms">
                <div class="service-block text-center">
                    <div class="service-icon text-center">
                        <i class="{{ .icon }}"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h3>{{ .title }}</h3>
                    <p>{{ .content }}</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            {{"<!-- End Single Service Item -->" | safeHTML }}
            {{ end }}
```

and the CSS for the section looks like:

```
.service-2 .service-item {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 50px 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.service-2 .service-item:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 65px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 65px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.service-2 .service-item:hover i {
  background: #fff;
  color: #57cbcc;
}

.service-2 .service-item i {
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #57cbcc none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: #fff;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 55px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
```

Is there a way to set a fixed height on those text boxes?

Comment: You can try to get the one with the highest height value in the `service-block` container via js, and then set this value on all containers.

Comment: js is an overkill. flexbox will do. I'll post my answer later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need js for this job. Add `display: flex` to the container of the blocks will do. The shorter children of the container will "grow up" to fit into the container.

```css
.flexcontainer{
  display: flex;
}

.flexchild{
  border: solid;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 100px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">
  <div class="flexchild">
    <h3>title </h3>
    <p>asdf</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flexchild">
    <h3>title </h3>
    <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flexchild">
    <h3>title </h3>
    <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</p>
  <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</p>
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/tcgriffith/pen/LYYLoxO)

[I find this flexbox guide to be useful](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Thanks again for your help on this @tc-zhang; I'm really new to HTML-CSS, in my example, I have the text linked to a .yaml with .service-item i { }; and connecting the service items to the html - do I need to specify the bootstrapped columns still and add the flexbox container to those?

Comment: ```          <article class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-12 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="500ms">
                <div class="flexcontainer">
                    <div class="flexchild">
                        <i class="{{ .icon }}"></i>
                        <h3>{{ .title }}</h3>
                        <p>{{ .content }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>

Comment: Your code looks fine. I'm also using blogdown/Hugo so could you share your repo, I'll have a look.

Comment: Here is the repo https://github.com/pembletonc/SOOSC_2019_SPLASH.git ; I didn't change the css or html on the repo, the text cols were getting a bit messed up with my flexbox changes. The files are in: style.css (line 1104, Services Section 2) and  themes/meghna-hugo/layouts/partials/ service.html . If you give me your information, I'll give you proper credit for your help!

Comment: Found the problem. add `height:100%` for `.service-block` at here https://github.com/pembletonc/SOOSC_2019_SPLASH/blob/master/themes/meghna-hugo/assets/css/style.css#L1091.

Comment: Wow, such a simple fix afterall. Thank you very much, and for your help on the other questions I've had on this project.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getHeight(el) {
  var styles = window.getComputedStyle(el);
  var height = el.offsetHeight;
  var borderTopWidth = parseFloat(styles.borderTopWidth);
  var borderBottomWidth = parseFloat(styles.borderBottomWidth);
  var paddingTop = parseFloat(styles.paddingTop);
  var paddingBottom = parseFloat(styles.paddingBottom);
  return height - borderBottomWidth - borderTopWidth - paddingTop - paddingBottom;
}

var heightList = [];
document.querySelectorAll('.service-block').forEach(function(el) {
  heightList.push(getHeight(el))
})

var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, heightList);
document.querySelectorAll('.service-block').forEach(function(el) {
  el.style.height = maxHeight + "px";
})
```

```css
.service-block {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
}

.service-block p {
  word-break: break-all;
}

.col-md-3 {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="service-block text-center">
        <div class="service-icon text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        </div>
        <h3>title</h3>
        <p>content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="service-block text-center">
        <div class="service-icon text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        </div>
        <h3>title</h3>
        <p>content.content.content.content.content.content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="service-block text-center">
        <div class="service-icon text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        </div>
        <h3>title</h3>
        <p>content.content.content.content.content.contentcontent.content.content.content.content.contentcontent.content.content.content.content.contentcontent.content.content.content.content.contentcontent.content.content.content.content.contentcontent.content.content.content.content.contentcontent.content.content.content.content.content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

This is my way, get the maximum height and set it to each container.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try to implement it and will get back to you. Should that css override what is currently there?

Comment: @CoreyPembleton This is just an example, you can refer to this piece of js code, do not pay attention to css~